# JQuery mouseover function firing multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have been using this method for a long time to set events for entire classes (for buttons etc):

```
$("div.bigButton").mouseover(function() { this.style.backgroundColor = '#dfdfdf'; });
```

However while doing some testing I have just noticed that when moving the mouse over these objects, the function fires 3 times! This is unnoticable when changing something like backgroundColor, but if I add an alert it's very obvious.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? I am concerned this may have an impact on performance later on.

Thanks

EDIT: Sorry, missing "style" off was a typo

The HTML is:

```
<div class="bigButton">
Test</div>
```

Comment: Provide sufficient data to answer your question.

Comment: better you provide a fiddler link

Comment: isn't it `this.style.backgroundColor`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have discovered that **the function that sets up the buttons was being run multiple times** (each time the page content was delivered via ajax). I would have thought this would *overwrite* the 'mouseover' function, but it seems it was adding to it instead!

Thanks for all your help

Answer (score 8):

This may be occurring because of nesting in your HTML elements. The jQuery documentation has a perfect example of this at the bottom of the page (don't confuse `mouseover` and `mouseenter`), as well as an example that prevents that unwanted behavior. http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/

Answer (score 4):

If it's a hover effect you should use `.hover` or `.mouseenter` and `.mouseleave`.

Also check for events bubbling from child elements that might be your problem.

**Update**

By trying this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CAL8u/) I can't seem to reproduce your problem, so your problem lies in your HTML/JavaScript code. Maybe you're attaching the handle three times?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried mouseenter and it does the same. It also does it on a basic DIV with no child elements, so I think the issue may be elsewhere!

Comment: I've tried your code in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CAL8u/) and it didn't reproduce the issue, I updated my answer.

Comment: Same result here - please see my answer below :)